# Multiple Domains w/ Single Laravel Install

Tags: php, laravel, mamp, laravel-5.7, mamp-pro

Sort of consolidating a few questions that are old, unresolved, and kind of in keeping with my own problem.

Routes file:

```php
echo url()->current() ."<br>";

echo request()->getHost();

Route::domain('pro.local')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', function () {
    dd('HELLO');
  });
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'pro.local'], function() {
    dd('PRO');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'media.local'], function() {
    dd('MEDIA');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'software.local'], function() {
    dd('SOFTWARE');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**Desire & environment:** Three domains pro.local, media.local, and software.local all pointing to the same `public` folder using MAMP PRO 5.2 and Laravel 5.7. This is all I have done to the project so far.

**Hypothesis:** Using `Route::domain` or `Route::group` should result in returning the `dd()` text or the `welcome` template.

**So far:** I know the mono-repo setup I'm using works because I've had the three sites running off the mono-repo for about 3 years and can share the services and what not across projects. With that said, it's annoying to have to SSH into three separate folders to run `composer update` and `npm update`; especially when the `composer.json` and `package.json` files for each project is essentially the same...I currently use `gulp` to move and copy files around to keep things in sync.

**Problem:** No matter the domain, only PRO gets echoed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It seems to skip the `Route::domain` and settle on the first `Route::group`, as demonstrated by moving the `dd('MEDIA')` call to the top.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code inside a `Route::group` *always* gets run, as Laravel compiles the various route definitions for later use. Thus, your `dd()` is getting executed as Laravel builds the list of routes, short circuiting the entire process regardless of what domain you're on.

If you put each of your debugging `dd` calls within a `Route::get('/', function () {})` inside each route group (like you do the first time with the `Route::domain('pro.local')` bit), you'd get the results you expected.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'pro.local'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        dd('PRO');
    });
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'media.local'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        dd('MEDIA');
    });
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'software.local'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        dd('SOFTWARE');
    });
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

ALTERNATIVE: Switching them all to use `Route::domain` also ended up working per discovery on another forum.